# Karma Failing to Run Tests : Executed 0 of 0 ERROR

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Currently I am following the Angular Fundamentals course by Jim Cooper on Pluralsight. I am doing everything exactly the same as him with the same versions etc. However I cannot get my Karma tests to run.

This is what my `karma-test-shim.js` file looks like:

```
// #docregion
// /*global jasmine, __karma__, window*/
Error.stackTraceLimit = 0; // "No stacktrace"" is usually best for app testing.

// Uncomment to get full stacktrace output. Sometimes helpful, usually not.
// Error.stackTraceLimit = Infinity; //

jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 1000;

var builtPath = '/base/app/';

__karma__.loaded = function () { };

function isJsFile(path) {
  return path.slice(-3) == '.js';
}

function isSpecFile(path) {
  return /\.spec\.(.*\.)?js$/.test(path);
}

function isBuiltFile(path) {
  return isJsFile(path) && (path.substr(0, builtPath.length) == builtPath);
}

var allSpecFiles = Object.keys(window.__karma__.files)
  .filter(isSpecFile)
  .filter(isBuiltFile);

System.config({
  baseURL: 'base',
  // Extend usual application package list with test folder
  packages: { 'testing': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' } },

  // Assume npm: is set in `paths` in systemjs.config
  // Map the angular testing umd bundles
  map: {
    '@angular/core/testing': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/common/testing': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/compiler/testing': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser/testing': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/http/testing': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/router/testing': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/forms/testing': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms-testing.umd.js',
  },
});

System.import('systemjs.config.js')
  .then(importSystemJsExtras)
  .then(initTestBed)
  .then(initTesting);

/** Optional SystemJS configuration extras. Keep going w/o it */
function importSystemJsExtras(){
  return System.import('systemjs.config.extras.js')
  .catch(function(reason) {
    console.log(
      'Warning: System.import could not load the optional "systemjs.config.extras.js". Did you omit it by accident? Continuing without it.'
    );
    console.log(reason);
  });
}

function initTestBed(){
  return Promise.all([
    System.import('@angular/core/testing'),
    System.import('@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing')
  ])

  .then(function (providers) {
    var coreTesting    = providers[0];
    var browserTesting = providers[1];

    coreTesting.TestBed.initTestEnvironment(
      browserTesting.BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
      browserTesting.platformBrowserDynamicTesting());
  })
}

// Import all spec files and start karma
function initTesting () {
  return Promise.all(
    allSpecFiles.map(function (moduleName) {
      return System.import(moduleName);
    })
  )
  .then(__karma__.start, __karma__.error);
}
```

This is what my `karma.conf.js` file looks like:

```
// Karma configuration

module.exports = function(config) {
    var appBase    = 'app/';       // transpiled app JS and map files
    var appSrcBase = 'app/';       // app source TS files
    var appAssets  = '/base/app/'; // component assets fetched by Angular's compiler. all assets served up at http://localhost/base/

  config.set({
    basePath: '',

    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
    ],

    files: [
      'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',

      // Polyfills
      'node_modules/core-js/client/shim.js',
      'node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js',

      // zone.js
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/sync-test.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/async-test.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/fake-async-test.js',

      // RxJs
      { pattern: 'node_modules/rxjs/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false },
      { pattern: 'node_modules/rxjs/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false },

      // Paths loaded via module imports:
      // Angular itself
      { pattern: 'node_modules/@angular/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false },
      { pattern: 'node_modules/@angular/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false },

      { pattern: 'systemjs.config.js', included: false, watched: false },
      'karma-test-shim.js',

      // transpiled application & spec code paths loaded via module imports
      { pattern: appBase + '**/*.js', included: false, watched: true },

      // Asset (HTML & CSS) paths loaded via Angular's component compiler
      // (these paths need to be rewritten, see proxies section)
      { pattern: appBase + '**/*.html', included: false, watched: true },
      { pattern: appBase + '**/*.css', included: false, watched: true },

      // Paths for debugging with source maps in dev tools
      { pattern: appSrcBase + '**/*.ts', included: false, watched: false },
      { pattern: appBase + '**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false },
    ],

    mime: {
      'text/x-typescript': ['ts','tsx']
    },

    proxies: {
      // required for component assets fetched by Angular's compiler
      "/app/": appAssets
    },

    exclude: [
    ],

    preprocessors: {
    },

    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

However when I run `karma start` like he does in the tutorial I get this error message:

[image: Error Message]

He says I should ignore the message about `systemjs.config.extras.js` as this is optional. So I know it is not this causing the error. I have searched a lot and cannot find any solution.

He used these versions for Karma:

`npm i karma@1.3.0 karma-chrome-launcher@2.0.0 karma-jasmine@1.0.2 jasmine-core@2.5.2 @types/jasmine@2.5.38 -D`

I also tried installing the latest version of chrome as well as the latest versions of Karma.

This is what my `package.json` looks like in case you want to see the versions he uses:

```
{
  "name": "ng2-fundamentals-demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run server\" ",
    "server": "node node_modules/ng2f-server/server.js",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "4.0.0",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "ng2f-bootstrap": "^0.0.4",
    "ng2f-server": "^0.2.3",
    "reflect": "^0.1.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.12",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "toastr": "^2.1.4",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^7.0.3",
    "@types/core-js": "0.9.34",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "6.0.46",
    "concurrently": "3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.5.2",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "typescript": "2.1.1"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

I also tried re-installing the `node_modules` file and it still fails to run the single test that I have. I am not sure what else I should try? Does anyone have any suggestions? Let me know if there is more info that I should provide. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution.

I had to run `npm start` which starts the server and compiles the code in a separate command window.

I then ran `karma start` while it was running and it worked.

Hopefully this helps someone else  :)